# After suspend screen gets distorted kde

Tags: kde, kubuntu

I'm using kubuntu 18.04 and from time to time after suspend instead of lock screen I get distorted screen like this:
[image]
When it happens there is no response from computer and whatever I try to do with keyboard or mouse nothing changes. Only when I move mouse there are nine lines moving like mouse pointer:
[image]

All I can do is just reboot computer and after that systems starts normally.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to specify to the system that upon resume the video kernel module needs to be reloaded.